# Android - Google places API | how to desable selecting the place from the search bar

Tags: android, google-places-api

i`m using Android - Google Api Places 
i want use its search bar just for searching 
- means : when the user search for a place on the search bar when he click on the search bar suggestions i don`t want to select this place as a result , i just want to navigate to this place on the map so he can make sure its his right place and he could select it from the select button

```
 private void startPickerEntity()
{
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try{
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent , 1);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==1 & resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        displayResults(data);
    }
}

private void displayResults (Intent data){
    Place selectedPlace = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
    String name = selectedPlace.getName().toString();
    String address = selectedPlace.getAddress().toString();

    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLoactionDetails);
    txtView.setText(name + " ** "+address);

}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have developed and indicate what is not working.

Comment: there is no error in my code , this is the default behavior of the place picker and i want to customize it , i just want to disable this selection from the search bar

Comment: With you code it would be easier to tell you exactly which part of you code needs to be changed in order to get the behavior you desire.  And please read this:: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and this :: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Barns here is my code